# Fixed marker on google maps for android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to put a fixed marker in the middle of the screen where my map is located, and that marker will give me the other marker information that is nearby and provide me the neighborhood information where the marker is. Is this possible ? How can i do that ? I see a lot of apps having this functionality.

**Edit:**
where Should i use `mMap.getCameraPosition().target` Method? on CameraMoveListener?i want when CameraMove stopped this method starts

**Answer** Use this Method on `mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use Relative or FrameLayout and put one Marker ImageView in center of the screen. 
Considering that the whole screen is of Mapview.
Now to get the centerpoint latitude and longitude you can use

```
mMap.getCameraPosition().target
```

That will be the exact position of your centered ImageView.

You can achieve Uber like location picker in same manner.

Comment: thanks a lot its working but i have another question i should implements locationListener and do this method on location changed?where should i add this?i add this on LocationChanged but its just working first time camera moves

Comment: thanks a lot i did it i should do it onCameraMove interface right?and its shows the latland of the center of the camera?

Comment: you can use it. For that you need to have your custom MapFragment and override onTouchListner. You can achieve in that.